# Initialize a string with data from property file in controller

Tags: spring, controller, metadata

I would like to Initialize a string with data from a property file in a spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

private string dbName;

.....
....
}
```

and in my property file: (`myApp.properties`)

```
dbName=EMPLOYEE
```

I found an example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/metadata/) but in the example of sun, they use an `init()` method. But where should I call my `init()` method as there is no constructor of the Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the configuration into a different class, initialize that class through spring XML definition like this :

```
<bean id="configuration" class="examples.Configuration">
  <property name="dbNAme" value="EMPLOYEE">
</bean>
```

create a class like this :

```
public class Configuration {

    public string dbName;

}
```

then reference it from your code.

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired    
    private Configuration config;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but (for me) the response is incomplete: I mean, in the controller to get the value of each property, you used something like config.????

Comment: OK that's the way it's working: so in the controller, you have to use: config.dbName instead of dbName.  Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: @Zamboo I am glad it is working, but I must mention that configuring DB name is usually not done this way. DB name is part of the JDBC connection string which is managed by your application server as a JNDI resource